# RAII-style lockable objects

Tags: c++, locking, winapi, c++03, raii

I am working on a Windows project using C++03 (C++11 is not an option), and without using Boost. I have several resources that are accessed by multiple threads at various times - a queue, for example, with data added by one thread and removed by another.  Individual methods of the involved classes generally perform locking internally.  However in some cases I need to lock the entire resource to perform a sequence of actions without another thread getting in the way.

Without the phrases "use Boost" and "use C++11", does the posted code for RAII-style locking of a resource look correct and safe, or is there something I've missed?

To this end I have written a simple RAII-style locking class, so that the following can be performed:

> ```
> void somefunction(void) {
>     GetLock<LockableClass> lock(queue);
>     ...
> }
> ```

Here the only requirement of `LockableClass` is that is has `Lock()` and `Unlock()` methods.  Specialisations of the class are provided for `CRITICAL_SECTION`, etc.

However, in the case of there being several queues, only some of which need to be locked at one time, I would like the following to be possible:

> ```
> void somefunction(void) {
>     list<GetLock<LockableClass> > locks;
>     for (vector<LockableClass>::iterator its = queues.begin(); queues.end() != its; ++its)
>         if (some_condition)
>             locks.push_back(GetLock<LockableClass>(*its));
>     ...
> }
> ```

In order to achieve this I've added a copy-constructor to `GetLock`.  This creates the requirement that any lockable object has to have some kind of reference counting.  It also limits me to using a `std::list` as the container for the locks - at least in my version of Visual Studio (2008 - yes, yes, I know).  `std::vector` appears to default-construct, then assign.

The following is the code for `GetLock`, along with a specialisation for `CRITICAL_SECTION`:

```
template <typename TLOCKABLE>
class GetLock {
private:
    TLOCKABLE& lock;
    GetLock();
public:
    GetLock(TLOCKABLE& plock) : lock(plock) {
        lock.Lock();
    }
    GetLock(TLOCKABLE* plock) : lock(*plock) {
        lock.Lock();
    }
    GetLock(const GetLock<TLOCKABLE>& plock) : lock(plock.lock) {
        lock.Lock();
    }
    ~GetLock(void) {
        lock.Unlock();
    }
};

template <>
class GetLock<CRITICAL_SECTION> {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION& lock;
    GetLock();
public:
    GetLock(CRITICAL_SECTION& plock) : lock(plock) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
    }
    GetLock(const GetLock<CRITICAL_SECTION>& plock) : lock(plock.lock) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&lock);
    }
    ~GetLock(void) {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&lock);
    }
};

// There is also a specialisation for HANDLE, to cope with mutexes...
// This presents its own issues as HANDLE is used everywhere in Windows,
// but differentiating between a Mutex and something else is a question
// for StackOverflow.
```

Does the code look safe? Is there something I've missed? Is making the assumption of using recursively-lockable objects a foolhardy thing to do? What could I do better?

Comment: `std::vector appears to default-construct, then assign`. No It copy constructs into place. Because you have already created the object before the `push_back` is called.

Comment: Usually when you have multiple lockable objects. You want to acquire them in a specific order (order to avoid deadlock). TO do this you must also release locks that you previously held if they are not acquired in the correct order.

Comment: @LokiAstari: You're right regarding the `push_back`, but it seems that `std::vector` requires `op=` to be declared too, which is where my original code failed. I've updated my question with the "final" code, which I think works quite well. And yes, normally you may need to lock in a specific order, but for my purpose it's not so necessary... just that they all be locked prior to "some process".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first I suggest you use *pointers* to keep the mutex reference; this makes it possible to have a non-owning state when the pointer is 0 (the state when default initialized)

also you created a **copy constructor** and a **destructor**, so you still need a **copy assignment** to properly follow rule of 3 (or at least disable it)

```
GetLock<TLOCKABLE>& operator=(const GetLock<TLOCKABLE>& plock) {
    if(plock.lock != lock){
        GetLock<TLOCKABLE> tmp(plock); 
        swap(tmp);

    }
    return *this;
}
```

however this keeps the assumption that the lock is recursively-lockable, but as an optimization it won't reacquire and release when the locks are the same

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about at least declaring `operator=`. And I'm not sure why I went with a reference, but changing to a pointer would allow your code above, and hence allow putting locks into a `vector` (if I allow default construction). Good stuff, thanks.

Comment: @icabod: Just change the internal representation to pointer. Maintain the interface that passes by reference.

Comment: @ratchet You should use copy and swap idium for assignment operator. Its exception safe while this is not. If `lock->Lock()` throws then you fail to call `tmp->Unlock()`

Comment: @LokiAstari: Good call on the copy-swap... the whole point of this class is to be exception safe. If I'm swapping to a pointer to the lockable object, then it makes copy-swap simple. Thanks.

Comment: @icabod yeah then the entire if block will be just `GetLock<TLOCKABLE> tmp(plock); swap(tmp);` with swap just swapping the lock pointers (which is exception safe)